How to make two Category filter dependent in Google Charts API
I am trying create an Dependent Category filter and charts. I have State Category Filter & City Category filter. On selection on State filter I have to filter the City category filter and the chart.
I have built  two DataTable - State DataTable & City DataTable like below
State DataTable:



Date
ST1
ST2




Jan-2024
100
150


Feb-2024
200
250


Mar-2024
300
350


Apr-2024
400
450


May-2024
500
550



City DataTable:



Date
ST1~ NY
ST1~ NJ




Jan-2024
50
50


Feb-2024
100
100


Mar-2024
200
100


Apr-2024
150
250


May-2024
300
200



I am following this question to understand Combining two types of Category Filter in Google Charts API
But Data format seems to be different, I would like to understand how I can build an two charts from these two DataTables and filter City Category filter on the selection of State Filter.
Below are piece of code I am working
var stcolumnTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
stcolumnTable.addColumn('number','colIndex');
stcolumnTable.addColumn('string','colLabel');
var st_initState={st_selectedValues:[]};

var cycolumnTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
cycolumnTable .addColumn('number','colIndex');
cycolumnTable .addColumn('string','colLabel');
var cy_initState={cy_selectedValues:[]};

for(var i=1 ; i < state_dtbl.getNumberOfColumns(); i++){
   columnTable.addRow([i,state_dtbl.getColumnLabel(i)]);
   initState.selectedValues.push(state_dtbl.getColumnLabel(i));
};

for(var i=1 ; i < city_dtbl.getNumberOfColumns(); i++){
   columnTable.addRow([i,city_dtbl.getColumnLabel(i)]);
   cy_initState.cy_selectedValues.push(city_dtbl.getColumnLabel(i));
};

Passing Column values to Category filter like
var statepicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'state_div',
        dataTable: stcolumnTable,
        options: {
          filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
          ui: {
            labelStacking: 'vertical',
            allowTyping: false,
            allowMultiple: true
            }
          },
    // Define an initial state, i.e. a set of metrics to be initially selected.
    state: {'selectedValues': [0, 1]}
    });  

var cityepicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'city_div',
        dataTable: cycolumnTable,
        options: {
          filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
          ui: {
            labelStacking: 'vertical',
            allowTyping: false,
            allowMultiple: true
            }
          },
    // Define an initial state, i.e. a set of metrics to be initially selected.
    state: {'selectedValues': [0, 1]}
    });

Although I am following this example Combining two types of Category Filter in Google Charts API I am not very clear to use setChartView() in my scenario. And I am not sure how to draw the chart and do the functionality in google.visualization.events.addListener()
Any help with code snippet will be a good learning for me.

Finally I came up with the below solutions for my scenario.
function uniquelists(value,index,self){ // To remove duplicates in Array
      return self.indexOf(value)===index;
}

Define the Category filters for State & City
var statepicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'state_div',
        dataTable: stcolumnTable,
        options: {
          filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
          ui: {
            labelStacking: 'vertical',
            allowTyping: false,
            allowMultiple: true
            }
          },    
    state: st_initState
    });  

var cityepicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'city_div',
        dataTable: cycolumnTable,
        options: {
          filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
          ui: {
            labelStacking: 'vertical',
            allowTyping: false,
            allowMultiple: true
            }
          },
    // Define an initial state, i.e. a set of metrics to be initially selected.
    state: cy_initState
    });

To make the City filter Dependent on State I made the following changes in the  Chart View function

Define Two State, Row & View for two category filter Split and compare

    var st_state = statepicker.getState();
    var st_row;
    var st_view = {
         columns: [0]
    }
    
    var cy_state = cityepicker.getState();
    var cy_row;
    var cy_view = {
       columns: [0]
    }


Filter based on Column Headers, In my City Data Table ST1~NY means NY comes under State ST1, below function will split and add Cities to dependent_filter_array based on State filter selection

Function to split and compare Cities with State values


depdent_filter_array = [];
const dict = cy_initState.selectedValues.reduce(function(agg, item) {          
      var pair = item.split("~")
      agg[pair[0]] = agg[pair[0]] || [] 
      agg[pair[0]].push(item)
      return agg
      {})


Loop through States and call Dict to filter

for(var i = 0;i<st_state.selectedValues.length;i++){
    var sl_st = st_state.selectedValues[i];        
    depdent_filter_array.push(dict[sl_st]); 
}


Remove duplicates from Filtered array and remove Undefined if any

var merged = [].concat(...depdent_filter_array.filter(uniquelists));
merged = merged.filter(item=> item!==undefined);


Filter DataTables rows based on Category filter Selected values

for (var i = 0; i < st_state.selectedValues.length; i++) {            
     st_row = stcolumnTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, 
             value:st_state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
     st_view.columns.push(stcolumnTable.getValue(st_row, 0));
}        

for (var i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
     cy_row = cycolumnTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: merged[i]}])[0];
     cy_view.columns.push(cycolumnTable.getValue(cy_row, 0));          
}

st_view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
          return (a - b);
        });

        cy_view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
          return (a - b);
        });

st_chart.setView(st_view);
cy_chart.setView(cy_view);
st_chart.draw();
cy_chart.draw();

All the above codes should be inside setChartView function.

Listener to know when State or City filter values changes and draw filters after setChartView function.

    google.visualization.events.addListener(statepicker,'statechange', setChartView);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(cityepicker ,'statechange', setChartView);

    setChartView();    
    statepicker.draw();
    cityepicker .draw(); 

